# Visual Studio Project doesn't build when using MFC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I am building a small game and I would like to show off my progress to my friends by sending them the game.
When trying to send them the Release folder after building it they get the error that they're missing a Visual studio library. I read that I need to create a static MFC library but when I do so my project won't build.
My project is in /MT modus or whatever it is.

Should add Debug mode still builds fine!

It gives me one LNK1120 error message and a lot LNK2001 error messages.

**Errors:**

Error: LNK1120 70 unresolved externals

Error: LNK2001 unresolved external symbol

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. It's my first C++ project.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand, you send your friend the resulting EXE or the source code ?

Comment: @Max, I basically send him the complete release folder after building it. It then gave him the library error, I'm trying to fix that now but now it won't build at all.

Comment: Also some versions of VS, like the express editions are delivered without the MFC runtime. It could also be that.

Comment: @RobotMess I installed MFC runtime myself via the new project window.

Comment: @WouterVanacht: also on your friends computer?

Comment: A MFC application can be dynamically linked to MFC or statically. Your project seems to be linked dynamically. If it is linked dynamically, you will have to add the MFC DLL's to your EXE. For start, just use static libraries. Look in project properties for "Use of MFC".

Comment: @RobotMess No but my goal is to get it working by including everything inside the .exe

Comment: @ZDF My settings are: Use MFC in a static library

Comment: Could it have something to do with things I am including? That they're wrongly compiled? I am using GLEW, GLFW, SOIL and GLM.

Comment: @Wouter Vanacht I do not understand. Did you change your project settings to static and after that you are unable to build the release version, but you are able to build the debug version? Could you post the exact message for LNK2001 and 1120 (just one)?

Comment: @ZDF If i recall correctly I changed the project to static and the runtime library to /MT. I thought that would make it so that every lib gets included in the .exe.

Comment: @ZDF LNK1120: 80 unresolved externals
LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wWinMain@16

Thanks for thinking with me

Comment: @Wouter Vanacht Did you change the Character Set too? Put back the settings the way you remember and see if it builds.

Comment: Another option is for your friends to install the missing Visual Studio libraries. A one time event. They are [downloadable from Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2977003).

Comment: @ZDF yes I did, there was something wrong with combination with unicode and MFC. Maybe that was before properly installing MFC. let me try some things out!

Comment: @ZDF it does run in release mode with the following settings:
C++ -> Code generation -> runtime library = /MD. MFC = standard windows libraries. character set = empty.

Comment: @ZDF now what should be the way to go to get everything so that there is nothing needed besides the .exe?

Comment: @BoPersson I know that, but I want to include that in the .exe

Comment: @Wouter Vanacht You should leave all properties as generated by wizard, except for "Use of MFC". And you should change this option for both configurations (debug & release).

Comment: @ZDF And it returns the same erros (or at least 1120 and 2019 again)
looks like every error has to do with GLFW.

Comment: @Wouter Vanacht You, probably have some other changes, too. Check the "Character Set". It should be Unicode. If this does not work, go to Project Properties, c/c++ & Linker, Command Line and compare your options against a newly generated MFC (static) project.

Comment: @ZDF will do! thanks

Comment: @ZDF The command line thingy looks the same. Only all the include files from my project are different (and of course the path everywhere). Changed the character set to unicode and still fails to run.

Comment: @Wouter Vanacht I am out of ideas. Try a rebuild. You may also try to create a new project (static) and copy the files from your old project to the new one. Since your debug version is running, I still believe that you missed some option.

Comment: Please read the documentation: [Redistributing the MFC Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235264.aspx).